# using facebook connect in Symfony2

Tags: facebook, symfony

I am using facebook connect in Symfony2, I have done this successfully, but now I want to get the User information of the logged in user from facebook. How can I get the user's information from facebook? any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Read the documentation? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to log my user on /login page (coupled with javascript provided by facebook on facebook dev portal):

```
public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (null !== $this->securityContext->getToken() || $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route') !== 'login') {
        return;
    }

    $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $this->appId,
      'secret' => $this->appSecret,
    ));

    if ($userId = $this->facebook->getUser()) {
        $token = $this->facebookProvider->generateToken($userId);

        if (false === $token = $this->facebookProvider->authenticate($token, false)) {
            $userInfo = $this->facebook->api('/' + $userId);
            $token = $this->facebookProvider->generateToken($userId);

            /** create new user **/
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFacebookId($userId);
            $user->setUsername($userInfo['name']);
            $user->setLang($userInfo['locale']);
            $user->setEmail($userInfo['email']);

            $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->flush();

            $token->setUser($user);
        }

        $this->securityContext->setToken($token);
    }
}
```